# Php ссылки

Tags: php, ссылки

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как добавить к 1 ссылке знак "**←**", а ко второй "**→**"?

Вот код хлебных крошек на **Wordpress** (*выводится 2 ссылки из одной рубрики*):

```
<div class="sample-posts">
<h3>
<?php
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
$category_ids = array();
foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
$args=array(
'category__in' => $category_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'showposts'=>2,
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new wp_query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
$my_query->the_post();
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
}
echo '</ul>';
}
wp_reset_query();
}
?>
</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
```

Я так понимаю в это место (с worpress не знаком)? Делаем так:

```
$f = true;?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"rel="bookmark"><?php echo ($f)?"←":"→"; the_title(); $f=!$f;?></a>
<?php
```

Ну это, например. И стрелки на ссылках будут чередоваться. =)

Comment: Здравствуйте! Ваш код работает не совсем корректно: выводятся 2 ссылки, но рядом с ними одинаковый знак. Например:
<?php echo ($f)?"←":"→"; the_title(); $f=!$f;?></a> <?php 
выводится только ←

Comment: Советую их выводить как `&larr;` и `&rarr;` соответственно.